# MAC OSX, the order of variable path, RVM and GIT

Tags: ruby-on-rails, macos, git, command-line, path

I ask a question before which is: [Install another version of Git on mac osx lion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11311165/install-another-version-of-git-on-mac-osx-lion)

I got some general idea which is put the new version of git before old version in the .profile file of the path.

However, the problem is I installed ruby on rails on the mac before, and rvm set the path already, which means I can't edit it in the .profile file.

When I run echo $PATH, "/usr/bin/bin"(git with xcode) always before "/usr/local/bin"(latest version of git), which is not what I want. But in the .profile file, only /usr/local/bin is in the path.

I don't know how to change the order of the path.

Anyone knows that? Thanks

Comment: Voting to close - duplicate of [install another version of git on Mac OS Lion](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11311165/install-another-version-of-git-on-mac-osx-lion)

Comment: when I installed the ruby on rails, it will set the path for me...so I can't change the path in .profile file

Comment: Continue discussion in your duplicate question.

Comment: @ttt Your question isn't very clear, can you paste the output of "echo $PATH" and "cat ~/.profile"?